# datepicker doesn't work after changing the position of include file

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am trying to use https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. I am developing admin model of my project with bootstrap template.In that  my datepicker doesn't work if i change position include file,if it is included before jquery files it worked and my side bar doesn't work but if it it is included after jquery files my side bar works and date picker doesn't work.I dont understand why this is happening.Any help will be appreciated.Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">     

<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
**<%@include file="include/include.jsp"%>**
<script>        
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<%@include file="include/menu.jsp"%>

<div class="content-wrapper">
<section class="content-header">
<h1>
Dashboard
<small>Control panel</small>
</h1>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard">
</i>Home</a></li>
<li class="active">Dashboard</li>
</ol>
</section>
<br>
<div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
<section class="content">
<div class="row">
<div class="box box-info">
<div class="box-header with-border">
<h3 class="box-title">Exam Time Table</h3>
</div>
<form action="ExamTimeTable.jsp" method="post">
Exam Date <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">  
</div>
</div>      
</section>
</div>             
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my include file.

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is included exactly?

Comment: include is bootstrap file that came with template.